# Optimize a method that checks url segments issue

Tags: laravel, security, optimization, middleware, blacklist

I've been using a method in Laravel Middleware that checks for strings in any URL segment to block the IP if it matches the "blacklisted" strings.

In the beginning, I had just a few strings to check, but now, the list is growing, and when I tried to optimize it to use a `blacklist array`, I ended up in a complete mess in the code and in my mind.

I believe this can be done but can't figure out the best way to optimize this middleware. Below is a sample of the Middleware code with notes where I'm having trouble.

In the `handle($request, Closure $next)` method is calling the `$this->inUrl()` method for all the blacklisted strings.

I've tried to add a `protected $blacklisted` array, to be used in the `$this->inUrl()` but can't make it work.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions that would be much appreciated and welcome. I am also thinking of providing the code as a gist on GitHub when optimized.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

/**
 * Class VerifyBlacklistedRequests
 *
 * @package App\Http\Middleware
 */
class VerifyBlacklistedRequests
{

    /**
     * The array of blacklisted request string segments
     *
     * @access protected
     * @var array|string[]
     */
    protected array $blacklisted = [
        '.env', '.ftpconfig', '.vscode', ',git', '.git/HEAD'
        // etc...
    ];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($this->inUrl('.env')
            || $this->inUrl('.ftpconfig')
            || $this->inUrl('.vscode')
            || $this->inUrl('.git')
            || $this->inUrl('.git/HEAD')
 
           // many more checks below the above ones

        ) {
            // logic that blocks the IP goes here and working fine
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

     /**
     * Check if the string is in any URL segment or at the one specified.
     *
     * @access protected
     *
     * @param string|mixed $value   Segment value/content.
     * @param integer      $segment Segment position.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function inUrl(string $value, $segment = -1)
    {
        if($segment !== -1 && request()->segment($segment) === $value) {
            return true;
        }

        collect(request()->segments())->each(function ($segment) use ($value) {
            if($segment === $value) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the suggestions, kindly posted here, I ended up with a solution that uses some of the suggested methods.

The result ended up by reducing the pages' loading time by more than 1 second.

My final implementation:

1. Created a config file `security.php` which contains the blacklisted request strings, and a shortlist of whitelisted IPs.

The **security.php** config file

```
<?php
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Whitelisted IPs configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These are the settings for the whitelisted IPs. The array contains
    | the IPs that should not trigger the IP block.
    |
    */
    'whitelisted_ips' => [
        // whitelisted IPs array
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Blacklisted request strings configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These are the settings for the blacklisted request strings. The array contains
    | the strings that should trigger the IP to be blocked.
    |
    */
    'blacklisted_requests' => [
        '.env',
        '.ftpconfig',
        '.vscode',
        '.git',
        '.git/HEAD',
        '_profiler',
        '__media__',
        'administrator',
        //...
    ];
];
```

2. Optimized the middleware removing the loops on the `inUrl()` method

The **VerifyBlacklistedRequests** middleware

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

/**
 * Class VerifyHackingAttemptsRequests
 *
 * @property \Illuminate\Config\Repository|\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|mixed white_listed_ips
 * @property \Illuminate\Config\Repository|\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|mixed blacklist
 * @package App\Http\Middleware
 */
class VerifyHackingAttemptsRequests
{
    /**
     * @access protected
     * @var \Illuminate\Config\Repository|\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|mixed
     */
    protected $blacklist;

    /**
     * @access protected
     * @var \Illuminate\Config\Repository|\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|mixed
     */
    protected $white_listed_ips;

    /**
     * VerifyHackingAttemptsRequests constructor
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->blacklist        = config('security.blacklisted_requests');
        $this->white_listed_ips = config('security.whitelisted_ips');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @since  2.8.1
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $exists = false;

        foreach(request()->segments() as $segment) {
            if(in_array($segment, $this->blacklist)) {
                $exists = true;
            }
        }

        if($exists) {
            $this->blockIp($request)
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Method to save an IP in the Blocked IP database table
     *
     * @access protected
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return \App\Models\BlockedIp
     */
    protected function blockIp(Request $request, $notes = null)
    {
        // the logic to persist the data through the BlockedIp model
    }
}
```

In summary, the `inUrl()` method was removed, removing all the loops and method calls and, as mentioned above, the pages' loading time was sliced by more than 50%.

Thanks to all for the suggested methods which contributed to helping me solve the problem.

Comment: yes @McRui , using **array** & `in_array($segment, $this->blacklist)` is a good decision to optimize the checking speed :+1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if doing this will optimize the code but the code is much more readable I think.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

/**
 * Class VerifyBlacklistedRequests
 *
 * @package App\Http\Middleware
 */
class VerifyBlacklistedRequests
{

    /**
     * The array of blacklisted request string segments
     *
     * @access protected
     * @var array|string[]
     */
    protected array $blacklisted = [
        '.env', '.ftpconfig', '.vscode', ',git', '.git/HEAD'
        // etc...
    ];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //loop over the list instead of that long conditions
        foreach($this->blacklisted as $blacklistedItem) {
            if($this->inUrl($blacklistedItem)) 
            {
                // logic that blocks the IP goes here and working fine
            }
        }
    }

     /**
     * Check if the string is in any URL segment or at the one specified.
     *
     * @access protected
     *
     * @param string|mixed $value   Segment value/content.
     * @param integer      $segment Segment position.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function inUrl(string $value, $segment = -1)
    {
        if($segment !== -1 && request()->segment($segment) === $value) {
            return true;
        }

        foreach(request()->segments() as $segment) {
            if($segment === $value) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Nahu for your suggestion, but that does not seem to check the request segment strings. It will only check the ```$this->blacklisted``` array

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create literal routes, so it is easier to maintain. Go to `RouteServiceProvider` and create a new reading similar to web or api, so any route that is in that new file, it will ban/block the IP.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but in my point of view, if I understood your suggestion, would even be worse, since I would have to create a "fake" route for each blacklisted string (over 100 now)

Comment: Yes, why are you doing this as no one can access this files because those are not inside `public` folder ?

Comment: Those are just examples, and it's implemented as a security measure against vulnerability exploiters. It also allows not to flood the laravel.log with 404's and to report to AbuseIPDB. Most of the request segments don't even exist in Laravel (examples: 'phpmyadmin', 'shell.php', 'wp-admin', 'xmlrpc.php', etc.), but they trigger 404's and allows blocking hacking attempts from several IPs.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think you should be solving this issue through NGINX or Apache, instead of Laravel, as it is not a Laravel responsability and also you are doing this checks all the time, slowing a little bit your app when the web server should not even serve that bad URL

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just found the solution after the feedback here. I'll reply to my question with the solution as soon as it is allowed. But using ```array_diff_assoc($request->segments(), $this->blacklisted``` takes 0ms while the current code takes +5ms.  Because ```$request->segments()``` is already doing what my ```inUrl()``` method is doing and much more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use DB and make the blacklist as **indexed** in DB,
Database would handle and search for this itself with its inner Engine.

```
protected function urlWasInBlackList($segment = -1){
    $segmentStrings= $segment != -1 ? [request()->segment($segment)] : request()->segments();

    return DB::table('blacklisted')->select('*')->whereIn('pattern',$segmantStrings)->exists()
}
```

and using some function like this instead of the `inUrl()`. it will check against the forbidden words Against the DB.

---

### Update : Avoid DB

however DB handles this situation with its InnoDB engine quickly,
maybe you want to avoid DB, because of connection overhead or simply not dependent your project just because one functionality,

if you want to a avoid DB,
you have to check url with each **black listed word** with a *loop* and it would be `O(n)`,
and if you multiply *sections count*, it would be `O(n*m)`. The

Optimal way is to avoid loop, and make a **hash table** like what DB does.

so I go for hash_tables in php and found in the php [array doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
that php associative arrays are **hash map**.
and the function `array_key_exists()` is looking into hash table for keys, you can see in the php source for the `array_key_exists()` codes which addressing the **ht** as hash map here:

[array.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/578b785ecff5a8ba4a3784679e6c4d7e5f11bc20/ext/standard/array.c) line #6071

[zen_hash.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/8356da600b433320307f206d2029f0ccfe894fc5/Zend/zend_hash.h) line #529

so I suggest to use something like this:

```
protected array $blacklisted = [
        '.env' => null, '.ftpconfig' => null, '.vscode' => null, ',git' => null, '.git/HEAD' => null
      
    ];
```

for blacklist definitions.
and

```
    $segmentStrings= $segment != -1 ? [request()->segment($segment)] : request()->segments();

foreach(segmentStrings as $segmentString){
    return array_key_exists($segmentString, $blacklisted);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abilogos for your suggestion. Using the database was, and is, something that I always wanted to avoid.

Comment: you are welcome @McRui, I have updated My Answer to Avoid DB

Comment: Thanks for the update. Nevertheless, I've tested and for instance, for /.git/HEAD it returns false, maybe because of the slash.